# Specific Angular 2/4 & Meteor quickstart/tutorial?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I've been all over the Meteor and Angular-Meteor websites (and Angular-Meteor github) looking for a pure Angular 2/4 guide to using Meteor (all I can seem to find is an Ionic one).  Kind of confused as to how to use the CLI's together.  Does anyone have a tutorial or know the steps to setting this up without Ionic?  Or should I just be trying to follow the Ionic tutorial but using Angular CLI instead?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested.

I spent most the day trying to use https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor with my app (used the quickstart), copied most of my apps src into the clients/imports directory and tried to keep the same app structure as the one on github, with a bit of messing around was able to get the angular bit working however if you are planning on using @angular/material, especially with a custom theme then you're in for a world of hurt (quite a few issues and comments re importing scss mixins from node_modules on the meteor github, meteors build system doesn't seem to like it).

To make it all work properly, follow the steps in **The process I've done to recreate this** section at https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/examples/angularcli-meteor

If you already have an angular 4 app partially built then start in your apps root directory at step 3 (ng eject).

Instructions are fairly straight forward. Any steps where there isn't code examples (Now we need to create api/tsconfig.json) copy the file in question from the repo.

Hope that saves some others a heap of time.

Comment: thank you for that answer!  can we change our instructions to make it easier for people to find?